# What are the essentials for a livestream training room?

Tags: streaming, production, live-recording

I work for a nonprofit (which rules out consultants or big packages) and I’ve been tasked with setting up the a/v for one of our large training rooms. I’ve got about a dozen events over the next year that will need to be live streamed.

I’m wondering if i could get a little guidance in what you think the essential elements of a livestream kit should be. I’m looking for something that is decent but also doesn’t require a seasoned producer to run. At least until I have staff dedicated to this, I’d be running it myself with minimal technical assistance.

Some of the decisions I’m wrestling with:

Standalone device like a tricaster vs. software (wirecast) vs. a digital A/V mixer (perhaps coupled with Wirecast)? If I go just with software, do I need two machines? What’s the benefit there?
The best way to handle 2 video feeds if I don’t go with a tricaster or a/v mixer (which have multiple video inputs). Blackmagic intensity shuttle vs Ultrastudio mini recorder vs something else?
PTZ setup (X2) or HD cameras on a soloshot or a camranger?
I’m having a tough time figuring out what kind of LED panel setup for ceiling mounting, and if that’s the way to go. I’ve got a relatively low ceiling, but I was wondering if I could have those in scoops or some sort of recessed fixtures in the drop ceiling in front of the presenter.

I’d love any thoughts you’d be willing to share. One added challenge is that each individual piece of hardware has to be under $5k. Total budget is ~$10-15k (recognizing that it is permanently installed so no need for portable gear).

Thanks in advance for any thoughts you have.

Answer (score 2):

Use [OBS](https://obsproject.com) for the streaming, it can handle multiple inputs and is better than most softwares I have used for live streaming. Might require some time on YouTube watching tutorials but once it is set up you will be good to go.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I hadn't seen OBS before. This doesn't really resolve my hardware question though, which I still worry leaves me with the gamble of whether a single computer can handle all of the business of capture, production, and streaming without getting bogged down and losing stability. Any thoughts on that side of the question?

Comment: @Robert1er It depends on the computer for whether it is capable of handling that many processes, which isn't actually that many. So one computer is enough, I recommend custom building it. Whether the stream gets bogged down mainly depends on your internet speed and encoding preferences within OBS.